# How to use instance() or setProps() on a nested component in React Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a component that wraps another connected component and I need to wrap the parent with a Provider. However, I couldn't test the parent with setProps or instance unless it's the root. I cannot pass store directly into the connected component since this would break 20 other tests. I tried to use shallow instead of mount, but looks like setProps requires a mount. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

setProps does not need a mount https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setProps.md you can actually use it in shallow rendering. how ever you can also not wrap your component in a provider, you can always pass the store in the context. but you will still get the `connected` component. other way to test it would be to also export the pure component and test that w/o the store on shallow render mode.

Comment: Ok. I see that setProps doesn't need a mount, I guess I can try to play around with shallow. I'm still not understanding what the NOTE part is trying to say here: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/shallow.html

Comment: it means that you can only do shallow/mount of a single component, not an array of components.

Comment: My bad. This is the right link: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.html. Also, is there any way to get props from child component? There's another test that's calling setProps on the parent component.. but it's checking the props of the child component. Since I'm using shallow on the parent, I don't think it is rendering the child?

Comment: if is and inmidiate child you can get its props by doing `component.find(ChildType).first().[prop('propName')|props()]` where childType is the component class to look for i am using `first` assuming it would be the first instance but there is also, `last` and `at`. if the child component you want to test is deeply nested it won't be rendered at all. but that is not bad since is best to not test deeply nested components, rather to keep your tests shallow, unless you want to interact with the DOM i.e fire events or take snapshots, this is my opinion of course. some people might disagree.

Comment: for my case,  my parent component has a child component that is connected, which is why I need a Provider in the first place. I'm actually not testing the connected component.. I'm testing a button component that is a child of the parent component (sibling to the connected component.) In this case, I need to do a mount to render the button. But how can I call setState on the parent (wrapped with Provider) and check the props of the button?

Comment: you can skip the provider part if you pass in the store as context when you render and as for how to do all that stuff i would tell you to review, enzymes documentation